# AngularJS $http .then syntax difference causes TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to obtain data from `getAllDatas` method.

This works fine without any error:

```
var getAlldatas = function ($http) {
    var getuser = function (username) {
        return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };
```

This throws error:

```
 var getAlldatas = function ($http) {
     var getuser = function (username) {
         var pro = $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username).then(getThis);

         var getThis = function (response) {
             return response.data;
         };

         return pro;
     };
```

How ever i get the following error message for the second one

> angular.js:10071 TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

How is the second one different from first and why does this throw error?
Why don't both behave in a similar way?

Comment: In the second example the `var pro = ...` line is actually `var pro = $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username).then(undefined);` -> [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

Answer (score 4):

It's how JavaScript works. Function declarations are **hoisted** to the top of the code page while initializations aren't.

[Reference](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)--Thanks to @Andreas

You are defining `getThis` *after* you are using it.

Comment: Function _declarations_ are hoisted.

Answer (score 2):

Your second definition breaks into

```
 var getuser = function (username) {
    var pro, getThis;
    pro = $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username).then(getThis);
    getThis = function (response) {
        return response.data;
    };
    return pro;
};
```

And `getThis` is just `undefined` during assigning a value to the `pro` variable. This issue occurs due to immediate `.then` call and taking it's callback argument which is `undefined` in work. The next code fixes the problem:

```
 var getuser = function (username) {
    var pro = $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
              .then(function(result) { getThis(result); });
    var getThis = function (response) {
        return response.data;
    };
    return pro;
};
```

In this case the callback argument is not `undefined` and it will pass to the AngularJS properly, and `getThis` variable will have time to get it's value.

Answer (score 1):

use like this:

```
  var getuser = function (username) {
  var pro = $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
          .then(function(getdata) { getThis(getdata); });
  var getThis = function (response) {
    return response.data;
  };
  return pro;
  };
```